# How to create a dashed polygon border in C++?

Tags: qgis, symbology, c++, rendering

In my maps I have a symbol, his type is polygon, I want to change the line style of the border, actually is solid , I had to put it in dash

Is there a simple way to change it ? i think to the QgsLineSymbolV2 ?

Comment: what program are you using.  If its Arc you just go into symbology and then choose outline you prefer

Comment: no it isn't Arc, it is an application for an industrial project based on QGIS api c++ 2.8.2 and written in c++/QT 4.8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59682/how-to-set-marker-line-symbol-for-qgsvectorlayer-by-using-python)  post in the SE ..it is for python.Same method can be used for C++

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code in C++ based on the post here :
[How to set Marker Line symbol for QgsVectorLayer by using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59682/how-to-set-marker-line-symbol-for-qgsvectorlayer-by-using-python)

thanks to Durga for the link in his answer.

So here is the code in c++ to change the style of the border of a polygon, in this exemple the color is white and the penstyle is dashed.

```
QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry * MyRegistry = QgsSymbolLayerV2Registry::instance();
QgsSymbolLayerV2AbstractMetadata * MyLineMeta;

MyLineMeta = MyRegistry->symbolLayerMetadata("SimpleLine");

//create lineMap Properties
QgsStringMap MyLineMap;
QStringList MyLineMapProperties;
MyLineMapProperties <<"width" << "color" << "offset" << "penstyle" << "use_custom_dash" << "joinstyle" << "capstyle";
QStringList MyLineMapValues;
MyLineMapValues << "0.25" << "255,255,255" << "0" << "dash" << "0" << "bevel" << "square";
for (int i =0; i < MyLineMapProperties.size(); i++){
    MyLineMap.insert(MyLineMapProperties.at(i),MyLineMapValues.at(i));
}

QgsSymbolLayerV2 * MyLineLayer = MyLineMeta->createSymbolLayer(MyLineMap);

pLayer->rendererV2()->symbols()[0]->setColor(QColor("#c545c3"));
pLayer->rendererV2()->symbols()[0]->appendSymbolLayer(MyLineLayer);
pLayer->setRendererV2(lrenderer);
```

Now you can change the color or the pen-style, you can also add some properties if you need that, the properties list can be found in the book The PyQGis Programmer's Guide page 92 to 97

Comment: Always great to see people sharing their final solutions! +1